# Open PageIndex in RadGrid

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, telerik, radgrid

I have a RadGrid with paging enabled.

I want to know how to open a particular page on **Grid_PreRender** Event as I want to select an item that is not on first page.

Currently it doesn't open the page that the item is on, it just stays on the first page.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly simple and you can do it in your code behind and call it from your page load, find the position of the row you wish to show in your data source, in my case i've just used resultIndex, and determine which page it's on.

```
const int pageSize = 5;
var page = (resultIndex / pageSize);  //eg row 50 means page = 10
myGrid.CurrentPageIndex = page;
myGrid.Rebind();
```